# What does this expression give?

Tags: sequences-and-series, finite-differences

It is known that

$$f(x+n)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \Delta^k[f](x)$$

Also it is known that

$$\Delta^n [f](x)= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} f(x+k)$$

Now I encountered the following expression:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} \Delta^k[f](x)$$

I wonder, can it be simplified. Am I correct it should be equal to $(-1)^n f(x-n-1)$?

Comment: Have you got an answer yet?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal  no